# PHP - how to keep the keep last ten of something in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP and I'm trying to keep an array of the last 10 post id's in Wordpress via `$_SESSION` array. I know I can add the latest post id like so:

```
$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'][] = $post->ID;
```

And similarly I could probably follow that command with something like this to remove ones greater than 10:

```
if( sizeof( $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] ) > 10 )
{
  array_shift( $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] );
}
```

However this won't work well if the user reloads the same post a few times, you could end up with something like:

```
Array
(
    [recently_viewed_posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456
            [1] => 456
        )

)
```

Desired behavior:

- The last 10 post id's will be keep in an array
- If a visited post is already in the array, it will move to the start or end of the array
- If the size of the array is 10 elements, and a new 11th post is visited, the oldest post id will be removed and the new post id added

I don't care too much about what side of the array (start or end) the new posts are on, as long as it is consistent. I don't really care what the array keys are.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

I tried searching for similar questions but didn't come up with anything useful so I apologize if this is a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'])) {
    $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] = array();
}
array_unshift($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'], $post->ID);
$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] =
    array_slice(array_unique($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts']), 0, 10);
```

This pushes new entries onto the beginning of the array, weeds out duplicates using `array_unique` (which keeps the first occurrence of an item) and limits the array to 10 entries. The most recent post will be at `$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'][0]`.

Comment: i was just thinking similar :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `$post->ID` as the key will make things more simple.

```
if (sizeof( $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] ) >= 10) {
    array_shift($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'][$post->ID])) {
    unset($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'][$post->ID]);
}

$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'][$post->ID] = 1;
```

Then `array_keys($_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'])` will give you the result.

Comment: i think using an integer as the array key will not preserve the order

Comment: wow, you're right. did this work differently in php4? for some reason i thought if you used a numeric key and did a print_r it would output in numeric order. guess i was wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TRY something like this ( not tested, just logic)

```
function addNew($new,$array)
{
  if(!in_array($new,$array))
  {
    if(sizeof($array) < 10){
     array_push($array,$new);
   }
   else{
    array_shift($array);
    addNew($new,$array);
  }
}

addNew($post->ID,$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'])
```

Comment: This doesn't move duplicate entries to the start of the array. More practically, it doesn't work because you're not passing the array around by reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get the Existing Post History, if there is one, or an empty array
$postHistory = ( isset( $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] ) ? $_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] : array() );

# Remove prior visits
if( $oldKey = array_search( $post->ID , $postHistory ) )
  unset( $postHistory[$oldKey] );

# Add the Post ID to the end of it
$postHistory[] = $post->ID;

# Trim the array down to the latest 10 entries
$postHistory = array_values( array_slice( $postHistory , -10 ) );

# Return the value into the Session Variable
$_SESSION['recently_viewed_posts'] = $postHistory;
```

Comment: You could just do `array_slice($array, -10)` instead of your double reverse. This also doesn't account for duplicate entries.

Comment: @deceze: Fair point. I tried testing that using an online php function sandpit, but it didn't behave as I had expected. (It was my first thought though.) And agreed - didn't cover instances of duplicates. Corrected that, though.